# Ruby: why does puts call to_ary?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, method-missing

I'm learning metaprogramming in Ruby and am just trying out defining missing methods via method_missing and define_method. I'm getting some unexpected behaviour and am wondering if anyone can explain this. Here is my class:

```
class X
  def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
    puts "method #{m} not found. Defining it."
    self.class.send :define_method, m do
      puts "hi from method #{m}"
    end
    puts "defined method #{m}"
  end  
end
```

Now, this code:

```
x = X.new

x.some_method
puts
x.some_method
puts
puts x
```

Produces the output:

```
method some_method not found. Defining it.
defined method some_method

hi from method some_method

method to_ary not found. Defining it.
defined method to_ary
#<X:0x007fcbc38e5030>
```

What I don't get is the last part: why is Ruby calling to_ary in a call to puts? Why would Ruby try to convert my object into an array just to print it?

I've Googled around and found these related links:

- http://tenderlovemaking.com/2011/06/28/til-its-ok-to-return-nil-from-to_ary/
- http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/02/the-craziest-fing-bug-ive-ever-seen/

These also talk about method_missing and to_ary gotchas, but not specifically about why puts would call to_ary.

I should also mention that the behaviour does not change when I define a to_s, e.g.

```
def to_s
  "I'm an instance of X"
end
```

The output of "puts x" is then:

```
method to_ary not found. Defining it.
defined method to_ary
I'm an instance of X
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`puts` is a synonym for `$stdout.puts`. $stdout is an `IO` class, so look at the documentation for [IO.puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> Writes the given objects to ios as with IO#print. Writes a record
>   separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with
>   a newline sequence. If called with an array argument, writes each
>   element on a new line.

This mean that `puts` method is intended to write several lines of output. Thus it tries to call `to_ary` method on an object and if `to_ary` is defined, then prints each element of the returned `Array` on a new line, else `puts` calls `to_s` method.

`to_ary` internal usage is really not well documented in the Ruby documentation (Matz points this out in his *The Ruby Programming Language* book).

Methods `print` and `p` on the other hand don't call `to_ary`, only `to_s`.

*Sidenote*: Interesting, that `to_ary` must return real `Array` object, not an object defining `each` method or something else:

```
class Test
  def to_ary
    10.downto(1)
  end
end

puts Test.new

#TypeError: can't convert Test to Array (Test#to_ary gives Enumerator)
#        from (irb):28:in `puts'
#        from (irb):28:in `puts'
#        from (irb):28
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the essence is "to_ary internal usage is really not well documented in the Ruby documentation" :) I just read the IO.puts docs, they do not explicitly mention to_ary, this should be clearer I think. Thanks for pointing to "The Ruby Programming Language" book, might check that out.